# ConcurrentDictionary Memory efficiency

Tags: c#, optimization, parallel-processing, k-means, concurrentdictionary

To put you in context: I'm implementing the KMeans algorithm using the netflix dataset in C#.

The dataset has this form:

```
8: // This is the movie id
23414, 3, 16/5/2009 //User id, rate, date
```

I'm storing the data as sparse points in the following data structures:

```
struct Point {
    double Norm {get; set;} // Vector norm
    ConcurrentDictionary<ushort, double> Values; // {movie:rate, ...}

    void CalculateNorm() { ... }
}
public class KMeans {
    ...
    Point[] _dataset = new Point[470758];
    ...
}
```

The problem is that once loaded the dataset occupies 4gb in RAM, I'm triggering the garbage collector manualy and it reduces the memory usage to half (2gb) but I'm looking for more optimum use of ram since I've solved this in C++ and the dataset was just 500mb in RAM.

Can someone give me advice on this? I left a link to the repo if you want to see the full code:
https://github.com/joalcava/Kmeans-CS/blob/master/Kmeans/KMeans.cs

Comment: What about profiling your app ?

Comment: I don't see how those values fit into the `Values` dictionary? Why not just use an array? Or 3 separate/individual values?

Comment: @aybe I have little expirience with profiling

Comment: Time to get started :) Press Alt+F2 and use the wizard in VS.

Comment: This isn't a `ParallelDictionary`, it's a `ConcurrentDictionary`. It means you can *write* to it using multiple threads. It doesn't use multiple threads itself. The plain-old Dictionary is already thread-safe for reading.

Comment: @RonBeyer Each movie represents a column of the matrix and each row represents a user, the cell is the rate. But one user can have rated only 1 or 20 movies and that vector will have all the other cells in 0, so with the dictionary i only store the actual rates, the key(the movie) represents the column and the value the rate(the cell).

Comment: As for memory waste, all containers grow by reallocating their internal buffers, typically by creating a buffer twice as large and copying data over. 2M of records can result in a *lot* or reallocations and garbage. Use the constructor that accepts a `capacity` parameter and set it to the expected size

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Oh sorry, I'm going to edit it.

Comment: @alecardv it's not about spelling. Unless you are writing multithreaded code this is the wrong class. *Before* writing multithreaded code though, check the [System.Numerics.Vectors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn858218%28v=vs.111%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) classes which allow you to use the CPU's SIMD instructions

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm using parallel.for and parallel.foreach all over the code.

Comment: @alecardv Are you inserting in to the dictionary after the initial data load? If not a normal Dictionary is perfectly thread safe in a read-only use case.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I'm doing some writes but in other dictionary so I'm going to left that one as parallel and put the main one as normal Dictionary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each Dictionary tends to have some overhead associated with it: several `int`s and some object references even when it's empty, and then as much as twice the space it needs once you start adding items. I assume `ConcurrentDictionary` is pretty much the same.

So instead of putting a new ConcurrentDictionary on every single Point, you might want to try having a single ConcurrentDictionary that's keyed off of both the point array index and the key you're currently using. C# 7's new tuple syntax should make this pretty easy to do.

Comment: It's a good point, Thank you. I'm going to try it and come back with the results.

Comment: Saved my day. Now the dataset is ~690mb on memory. Thanks!.